# Pagedown Editor Won't Work in Modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog, pagedown

I have the pagedown editor working fine in cases where the editor and code are present at pageload.

I am trying to get the pagedown editor to work in a modal dialog, where the form (e.g. textarea, etc) isn't in the dom until after the modal is activated. e.g. initially it is just a blank div

What could I be missing?

I am using the standard demo code from here 
https://github.com/balpha/pagedown/tree/master/demo

...again, only issue is that it doesn't work when I inject the html into a modal div after pageload.

Comment: you need to run the `var editor2 = new Markdown.Editor(converter2, "-second", options);`-style init stuff again when the modal is ready

Comment: @dandavis - That did the trick. If you want to post as the answer, I'll accept it.